# Django, админка, проверка связанных полей

Tags: django, django-admin

В админке есть BooleanField.
Я хочу, что бы это поле было не активным (input type="checkbox" disabled), если другое поле (ImageFile) не заполнено вообще.
Как это правильно сделать?
Если придется модель сохранить дважды - этот вариант устроит.

---

Никто не ответил за 4 дня. Что ж, вот мой вариант. Правда поведение странное. При первой загрузке страницы редактирования галка всегда не disabled (не правильное поведение). А при перезагрузке страницы становится disabled, как ей положено. Так же после сохранения модели - меняет поведение после перезагрузки. То есть если модель сохранить и дополнительно страницу перезагрузить, мы получаем то, что надо. :)

```
class in_stock_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        on_off = {} if self.instance.pic1 else {'disabled':'disabled'}
        in_stock_form.Meta.widgets = {'in_stock': CheckboxInput(attrs=on_off)}

@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = in_stock_form
    fields = (('artikul', 'category', 'in_stock',),
              ('fullname', 'slug'),
              ('price', 'sale_price', 'in_sale'),
              ...
```